# Event bus trigger duplicating

Tags: javascript, aspnetboilerplate

In the edit modal for my company entity, I open the address entity create modal. This allows the user to create an address for the company. On the .done of the address create app service method, I trigger an event using the abp.event.trigger method. The company edit modal then watches for this event so that it can create an entry into the companyAddress entity. Soon as the companyAddress entity app service method ends, on .done event, I turn off the event trigger. However, after the first instance of creating an address, when the user adds more addresses the trigger mechanism is firing multiple times and causing duplicate entries in the companyAddress table. I have debugged this over and over and read the docs for abp event triggers and cannot figure out how this happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

Create address modal js

```
    this.save = function () {
        if (!_$form.valid()) {
            return;
        }
        var address = _$form.serializeFormToObject();
        _modalManager.setBusy(true);
        _addressService.createAddress(
            address
        ).done(function (result) {
            abp.notify.info(app.localize('SavedSuccessfully'));
            abp.event.trigger('addressCreated', {
                id: result
            });
            console.log('addressCreated event triggered for id: ' + result);
            _modalManager.close();
        }).always(function () {
            _modalManager.setBusy(false);
        });
    };
```

Edit company modal js

```
    abp.event.on('addressCreated', function (item) {
        console.log('addressCreated event caught for id: ' + item.id);
        //Call company address service
        var _companyAddressService = abp.services.app.companyAddress;
        _companyAddressService.createCompanyAddress({
            CompanyId: $("#CompanyId").val(),
            AddressId: item.id
        }).done(function () {
            abp.event.off('addressCreated', {
                id: null
            });
            console.log('addressCreated event turned off for id: ' + item.id);
            abp.notify.success(app.localize('AddressCreated'));
            abp.ui.clearBusy('.modal-body');
        });
    });
```

Here is google chrome console showing the duplication.
[image]

I just tested the modals again, I entered about 8 different addresses via the create modal for 2 differnt companies. For this test, the duplication issue did not happen. But the issue where the event does not fire for each address created keeps happening. As you can see from the console log below, the ID number 2,3,5 and 6 did not generate the "started" log entry. My companyAddress table is also missing the entry for these 4 IDs, so the event did not trigger.
[image]

Edit company modal.js full **updated** code

```
var EditCompanyModal = (function ($) {
app.modals.EditCompanyModal = function () {

    var _modalManager;
    var _companyService = abp.services.app.company;

    var _$Form = null;
    this.init = function (modalManager) {
        _modalManager = modalManager;

        _$Form = _modalManager.getModal().find('form[name=EditCompany]');
        $(".modal-dialog").addClass("modal-lg");
        _$Form.validate();
    };

    this.save = function () {
        if (!_$Form.valid()) {
            return;
        }
        var company = _$Form.serializeFormToObject();
        _modalManager.setBusy(true);
        _companyService.updateCompany(
            company
        ).done(function () {
            abp.notify.info(app.localize('SavedSuccessfully'));
            _modalManager.close();
            abp.event.trigger('app.editCompanyModalSaved');
        }).always(function () {
            _modalManager.setBusy(false);
        });

        abp.event.off('addressCreated', addressCreated); // Turn off this handler
    };

    var _editModal = new app.ModalManager({
        viewUrl: abp.appPath + 'Nursing/Address/EditModal',
        scriptUrl: abp.appPath + 'view-resources/Areas/Nursing/Views/Address/_EditModal.js',
        modalClass: 'EditAddressModal'
    });

    var _createModal = new app.ModalManager({
        viewUrl: abp.appPath + 'Nursing/Address/CreateModal',
        scriptUrl: abp.appPath + 'view-resources/Areas/Nursing/Views/Address/_CreateModal.js',
        modalClass: 'CreateAddressModal'
    });

    $('#add_new_address').click(function (e) {
        _createModal.open();
    });

    $('#addressTiles').on('click', '.btnEditAddress', function () {
        var addressID = $(this).parent().find("input").first().val();
        _editModal.open({ id: addressID });
    });

    abp.event.on('addressCreated', addressCreated);

     //After address create event, save company address Id
    function addressCreated(item) {
        console.log(new Date().toUTCString() + ' - addressCreated started for id: ' + item.id);
        //Call company address service
        var _companyAddressService = abp.services.app.companyAddress;
        _companyAddressService.createCompanyAddress({
            CompanyId: $("#CompanyId").val(),
            AddressId: item.id
        }).done(function () {
            console.log('addressCreated event turned off for id: ' + item.id);
            abp.notify.success(app.localize('AddressCreated'));
            abp.ui.clearBusy('.modal-body');
        });
    }

};})(jQuery);
```

Chrome console logs for updated JS code
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on [Register To Events](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Javascript-API/Event-Bus#register-to-events):

> You can use **abp.event.off** method to **unregister** from an event. Notice that; same function should be provided in order to unregister. So, for the example above, you should set the callback function to a variable, then use both in **on** and **off** methods.

You're passing in a dummy object:

```
abp.event.off('addressCreated', {
    id: null
});
```

Do this:

```
function addressCreated(item) {
    console.log('addressCreated event caught for id: ' + item.id);
    //Call company address service
    var _companyAddressService = abp.services.app.companyAddress;
    _companyAddressService.createCompanyAddress({
        CompanyId: $("#CompanyId").val(),
        AddressId: item.id
    }).done(function () {
        abp.event.off('addressCreated', addressCreated); // Turn off this handler
        console.log('addressCreated event turned off for id: ' + item.id);
        abp.notify.success(app.localize('AddressCreated'));
        abp.ui.clearBusy('.modal-body');
    });
}

abp.event.on('addressCreated', addressCreated);
```

> The addressCreated function is executing not at all sometime[s]

You're only calling `.on` once per `EditCompanyModal`, and then `.off`-ing it.

<s>Move the .off into this.save = ....</s>

## [Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915120/create-app-service-call-executing-multiple-times/47929064#47929064)

Move the `.off` into `this.init = ...`.

```js
this.init = function (modalManager) {
    _modalManager = modalManager;

    // ...

    _modalManager.onClose(function () {
        abp.event.off('addressCreated', addressCreated); // Turn off this handler
    });
};
```

Comment: I tried that change, but now I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: addressCreated is not defined" on the abp.event.off line

Comment: It worked, but as I kept testing further, the duplication is still happening, every now and then. The addressCreated function is still executing multiple times, and not at all sometime. I have updated my post to show the latest chrome console logs.

Comment: yeah in the latest console image I shared the problem is that the trigger event did NOT fire for ID 2 &3. Other times it fires multiple times for the same ID.

Comment: I have updated my post with my latest testing showing the chrome console. I have also added the JS code for the event trigger.

Comment: added another image showing the full code for the editmodal.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161412/discussion-between-exlnt-and-aaron).

Comment: That did not work. It makes things worse, now the companyAddress table is not getting updated at all. Plus when adding/editing addresses the save event on the company edit modal is not required,

Comment: Thanks for your help! The duplication is still happening, dont know why! I'm going to handle this issue in my app service and not allow duplicate entry to get added.

Comment: You're welcome! Updated the answer and cleaned up my comments. Please post a new question if you encounter new problems.